# Update database table cyclically every 5 minutes

Tags: php, mysql, performance, mysqli, cyclic

I have to populate and update one of my MySql database table using a complex and expensive query, based on selection from other table's data. This table doesn't need to be always fully updated when i make a query on it, but i'd like to have a cyclic update every 5 minutes.

This automatic update should be infinite and i need to be sure that it never stops.

After some research, i've found some solution, but i don't know which is better for security and performance.

One of these could be my goal:

1. Don't create table and make complex query from php every time to get the desired result
2. Create a php script that repeats cyclically and update table db, maybe using Cron Job.
3. Update table using a sql event

I think that first solution could be to expensive since query is complex and there could be many request every second, but the result is always updated. I don't have experience about Cron Job, so i can't know if it could be a good idea or not. For the third solution, i still don't have database privileges to run events, but i'd like to know if it could be a valid solution.

All other solutions are welcome, thanks.

Comment: solution #2 could be optimal, a cronjob-triggered php scipt that handles the update of your table. are you caching queries results in it?

Comment: No, i don't need to cache results queries because i don't have to output them. This table is used as a filter from a concatenation of other big tables. Something like a table that contains only 30 items, taken from other tables, that in that moment are the best for particular attributes. I don't know how to implement it with cron job, but can i be sure that loops will never stops?

Comment: you could create a `VIEW` in `MySQL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use cron.  Think about what will happen if one instance goes beyond 5 minutes and the next starts up.  Eventually you will have hundreds of copies bogged down stumbling over each other.

Instead have a single job in a loop doing the update.  (OK, you could have a cron job to perform a "keep-alive" task of restarting the query if it dies.)

The job would

```
CREATE TABLE new ...
INSERT INTO new  SELECT complex-stuff...
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;
DROP TABLE old;
loop.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for Cron Job.

1. It doesn't clog any request, since it's executed from the operating system.
2. You can define which user executes the script (`cron -u apache -e`).
3. Easy to define interval. (i.e. every 5 minutes `*/5 * * * * php /path/to/script.php`).
4. [It's loggable](http://www.emind.co/how-to/how-to-debug-cron-jobs).

### Additional Notes

I had a cron job running under **root** and it worked just fine. My problem was that the project had a private **logging mechanism** that each log file would be created by **apache** user. By running it from **root**, sometimes the file would be created by **root** and after that, the scripts being executed by **apache** would not be able to *APPEND* to the log.

I also had an emailing script that would run once every 2 minutes that got stuck for 1h. Turns out, because of a bug in the application, an invalid email address (somethingwithoutatsign.com) was inserted into the database, which made the PHPMailer library throws errors. After that, I added a **catch** block that would send an email to me whenever an exception was thrown. Now, if the script stops running because of bad execution, I get to know right away.